# How to Multicasting in python Without UDP range

Tags: python, linux, udp, ip, multicast

How to Multicasting using python in linux server

```
import socket
import struct

MCAST_GRP = '224.1.1.1'
MCAST_PORT = 5007
IS_ALL_GROUPS = True

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
if IS_ALL_GROUPS:
    # on this port, receives ALL multicast groups
    sock.bind(('', MCAST_PORT))
else:
    # on this port, listen ONLY to MCAST_GRP
    sock.bind((MCAST_GRP, MCAST_PORT))
mreq = struct.pack("4sl", socket.inet_aton(MCAST_GRP), socket.INADDR_ANY)

sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)

while True:
  # For Python 3, change next line to "print(sock.recv(10240))"
  print sock.recv(10240)
```

It was particular udp Only Multicasting.. but i need without udp range ... all udp are multicasting it Possible ?

Need to enable the multicast without udp range

I Have attach my server info :

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.103  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::338c:adf8:4268:e0f7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 40:a8:f0:68:c7:8a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.5.36  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.5.255
        inet6 fe80::6b15:5402:b1c5:9839  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 28:ee:52:05:c7:9a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
```

---

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth1
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 eth0
192.168.5.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth1
224.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         240.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 eth1
```

Thankyou

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What does "udp range" mean?

Comment: 224.1.1.1  it was particular udp only multicasted ... i want all udp are multicast with one script it possible ?

Comment: You're still not making sense.  I don't know what you mean by "all udp are multicast", as multicast is a property of IP, not of UDP.

Comment: i have new linux server ... how to enable multicasting using python for my linux server @dbush sir

Comment: route -n add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 dev eth1 it was multicasting command but it was not python ... i want python script for multicasting